# Social authentication in an iOS HTML application

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am starting a new client-side JS-based application using firebase.  I have Facebook authentication working properly (using popup-based authentication) when it is used on Desktop Safari / Chrome, as well as Safari on iOS.  What isn't working is when my app is added to the iOS Home Screen to run as an "application".  I have tried switching to redirect-based authentication but that does not seem to work either.

I would love to see an example of how to properly do this so it works from both desktop and as an iOS web application.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem is not authentication-related, but a problem with my event-handling due to the way jQuery Mobile loads pages using AJAX.  After looking closer, the script code in `<HEAD>` is not being executed for a new page being loaded.  I need to correct this and I think my authentication problems will go away.